# Alternatives to Cassandras Opscenter for people using the open source distribution

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

As DataStax will discontinue the OpsCenter (http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.2/opsc/opscPolicyChanges.html), which was rather okay for monitoring purposes and the daily management tasks,
I'm searching for a valid alternative. The list of tools under http://www.planetcassandra.org/related-projects/ does not really look attractive.
Is there a meaningful or even better way? OpsCenter already had very limited functionality for OSS. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra exposes own metrics via JMX, so you can use any tool that is able to collect JMX data.
On production environment we are using [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) for monitoring purposes.
Also we looked at [Graphite](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html) but we chose Zabbix because it is our "corporate standard"